# Alternative reference to Deligne pairing

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

Apart from the Deligne's original paper "Le déterminant de la cohomologie", is there any other reference presenting the construction of the Deligne pairing on arithmetic surfaces?

Of course there is "nothing wrong" with the original paper, I'm only looking for other sources.

Comment: The Deligne bracket is also discussed in http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~jongrsde/publications/thesis.pdf . You can also have a look at the work of Dennis Eriksson

Comment: The theory has been extended to higher dimensions by Renée Elkik. See her two papers, Annales scientifiques de l'École normale supérieure (construction of the intersection line bundle) and Duke Math. Journal (definition of a metric in the Arakelov case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Arbarello/Cornalba/Griffiths: "Geometry of algebraic curves II" p. 366-379.